# Material-UI: classes isn't working with external SVG icons?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, jss

I have created a Material-UI persistent drawer in which there is a list item component that aims to change the icon color whenever a user clicks on the list item. But my styling is only working with Material-UI icon, not with external SVG.

Here is codesandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/drawer-list-styling-r6xiw?file=/src/Drawer/components/DrawerListStyle.js:0-326) for the same project to understand it better.

**Here is my `AppBarDrawer.js` parent component that renders my listItem component. Working fine and can be ignored**

```
import React from "react";
import clsx from "clsx";
import { makeStyles, useTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Drawer from "@material-ui/core/Drawer";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
import List from "@material-ui/core/List";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Divider from "@material-ui/core/Divider";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";
import ChevronLeftIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ChevronLeft";
import ChevronRightIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight";
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
import ListItemIcon from "@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";
import InboxIcon from "@material-ui/icons/MoveToInbox";
import MailIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Mail";
import DrawerList from "./components/DrawerList";

const drawerWidth = 240;

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex"
  },
  appBar: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create(["margin", "width"], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen
    })
  },
  appBarShift: {
    width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(["margin", "width"], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen
    })
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2)
  },
  hide: {
    display: "none"
  },
  drawer: {
    width: drawerWidth,
    flexShrink: 0
  },
  drawerPaper: {
    width: drawerWidth
  },
  drawerHeader: {
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
    // necessary for content to be below app bar
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
    justifyContent: "flex-end"
  },
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
    transition: theme.transitions.create("margin", {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen
    }),
    marginLeft: -drawerWidth
  },
  contentShift: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create("margin", {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen
    }),
    marginLeft: 0
  }
}));

export default function PersistentDrawerLeft() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(true);

  const handleDrawerOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleDrawerClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar
        position="fixed"
        className={clsx(classes.appBar, {
          [classes.appBarShift]: open
        })}
      >
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
            onClick={handleDrawerOpen}
            edge="start"
            className={clsx(classes.menuButton, open && classes.hide)}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h6" noWrap>
            Persistent drawer
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Drawer
        className={classes.drawer}
        variant="persistent"
        anchor="left"
        open={open}
        classes={{
          paper: classes.drawerPaper
        }}
      >
        <div className={classes.drawerHeader}>
          <IconButton onClick={handleDrawerClose}>
            {theme.direction === "ltr" ? (
              <ChevronLeftIcon />
            ) : (
              <ChevronRightIcon />
            )}
          </IconButton>
        </div>
        <Divider />
        <List>
          <DrawerList />
        </List>
      </Drawer>
      <main
        className={clsx(classes.content, {
          [classes.contentShift]: open
        })}
      >
        <div className={classes.drawerHeader} />

        <Typography paragraph>
          Lorem Nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a
        </Typography>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**The Main file `DrawerList.js` which is not giving desired out**

Here the real issue is my external icons color is not changing to white whenever I click on it however the last icon named `ExitToAppOutlined` is a Material-UI icon and is working fine on click.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
import Link from "@material-ui/core/Link";
import ListItemIcon from "@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon";
import { ExitToAppOutlined } from "@material-ui/icons";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";
import { useStyles } from "./DrawerListStyle";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import { SvgIcon } from "@material-ui/core";

import { ReactComponent as Appointment } from "../../assets/Appointment.svg";
import { ReactComponent as Customers } from "../../assets/manage customers 2.svg";

const itemList = [
  {
    text: "Book Appointment",
    icon: (
      <SvgIcon>
        {/* external icons as svg */}
        <Appointment />
      </SvgIcon>
    )
  },
  {
    text: "Manage",
    icon: (
      <SvgIcon>
        {/* external icons as svg */}
        <Customers />
      </SvgIcon>
    )
  },
  {
    text: "Logout",
    // Material Icons
    icon: <ExitToAppOutlined />
  }
];

const DrawerList = () => {
  const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState(0);
  const classes = useStyles();

  const ListData = () =>
    itemList.map((item, index) => {
      const { text, icon } = item;

      return (
        <ListItem
          button
          key={text}
          component={Link}
          selected={index === selectedIndex}
          onClick={(e) => handleListItemClick(e, index)}
          style={selectedIndex === index ? { backgroundColor: "#6A2CD8" } : {}}
        >
          <ListItemIcon
            className={classes.iconStyle}
            style={selectedIndex === index ? { color: "#fff" } : {}}
          >
            {icon}
            <ListItemText>
              <Typography
                component="div"
                className={classes.iconTitle}
                style={selectedIndex === index ? { color: "#fff" } : {}}
              >
                <Box fontWeight={500} fontSize={13.5}>
                  {text}
                </Box>
              </Typography>
            </ListItemText>
          </ListItemIcon>
        </ListItem>
      );
    });
  const handleListItemClick = (e, index) => {
    setSelectedIndex(index);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <ListData />
    </div>
  );
};

export default DrawerList;
```

**`DrawerListStyle.js` just an stylejs file and can be ignored**

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(2)
  },
  iconStyle: {
    margin: theme.spacing(0, 0, 1, 0),
    color: "#6A2CD8"
  },
  iconTitle: {
    margin: theme.spacing(0, 0, 0, 1),
    color: "#555458"
  }
}));

export { useStyles };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Material-UI sets the `color` of your `ListItemIcon` when the `ListItem` is selected, but because your custom `svg` icons already have the `fill` attribute set to another color, it overrides the `color` from MUI. The fix is simple, override the `fill` attribute again in your custom svg using `makeStyles`:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  {...}
  listItem: {
    "&.Mui-selected": {
      "& path": {
        fill: "white"
      }
    }
  }
}));
```

```js
<ListItem className={classes.listItem}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 67092230/why-material-ui-classes-isnt-working-with-external-svg-icon]

Comment: Thank you so much! I just learnt a new thing from you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `SVGR` to build your own icons.

you can follow these steps:

1- install svgr using

```
npm install --save-dev @svgr/cli
# or use yarn
yarn add --dev @svgr/cli
```

2- add your icons in `public/icons`

3- create a file named `svgr.config.js` and place it in the root of project

```
module.exports = {
    icon: true,
    dimensions: false,
    expandProps: false,
    replaceAttrValues: {
        '#000': 'currentColor',
        '#292D32': 'currentColor',
        '#292d32': 'currentColor',
        '#55BB9D': 'currentColor',
        '#FFBC50': 'currentColor',
        '#A7A7A7': 'currentColor'
    }
};
```

4- add script in package.json
`"svg": "svgr --ext=jsx -d src/@share/icons public/icons"`

5 - run `yarn svg`.

once you run above command svgr grab all icons in the public folder and gerenate React component inside `src/@share/icons` folder based on the config you provided.
and replace every color text of svg into current color.
in this case replace every key in `replaceAttrValues` to the `currentColor`.

then in your react component you can simply do this:

```
import { MyIcon } from '@share/icons';
import { SvgIcon } from '@mui/material';

function MyComponent() {
    return <p><SvgIcon component={MyIcon} /> check this icon </p>
};

export default MyComponent;
```

in this way you can change the color the way you change the text color of `p` element.